# adb logcat - monitor hardware accesses

Tags: adb, hardware, logging

Is there a way to show hardware messages (low level, in particular, I’m interested to see messages related to audio, camera, and microphone) using `adb logcat`?

In my experiment regarding the microphone, I developed an app that records audio for Pixel 3a with Android 8. So I run the recording, and once terminated execute this command: `adb logcat -d -v uid -b all`. My expectation is to find some message that indicates access to the hardware, in this case to the microphone.

Comment: AFAIK, running `adb logcat` without parameters will show *all* messages, including hardware messages if they're coded to print some logs (may depend on the manufacturer and ROM). If it is still lacking, could you [edit] and clarify what you want to read?

Comment: The only log I am aware of that is "lower" than logcat is `dmesg` but AFAIK that requires root permissions.

Comment: I edited the question. I hope that the question was clear. If you want i can provide the code….

Comment: OP's follow-up question: [Dmesg Pixel 3a Android 8](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246543/44325)